# Line showing up between top of site window and bottom of chrome bookmarks

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure why but the image I'm using is displaying a white line at the top. This doesn't happen with other images.

I've zoomed in quite a bit on the image to make sure it's not the image itself. I set the box to black just incase the image didn't cover everything. Yet it's still there.

This is the site: http://www3.carleton.ca/clubs/sissa/html5/

This is what it looks like:

[image]

CSS:

```
body{
    width: 100%; /*always specify this when using flexBox*/ 
    height:100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-box-pack:center; /*way of centering the website*/
    -moz-box-pack:center;
    box-pack:center;
    background:black;
    background:url('images/bg/bg14.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-position: left top;
    -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
    -moz-background-size: cover !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Comment: So do you see this line with other sites?

Comment: I see a thin one. About the same size as the top line in the middle (non-highlighted). But the highlighted line is thicker and more obvious. When I use style2 (sidebar on left) the line there is about normal. (sorry if im not explaining it clearly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just because of the Chrome Theme you are using. Change the theme to default and you will not get that white line. I am not getting it on my Chrome!